# Why can't an index signature parameter type extend string or number?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote this simple function:

```js
function propertyMap<T extends string>(prop:T)
{
    return function<U extends {[key:T]:V},V>(record:U):V
    {
        return record[prop];
    };
};
```

And the compiler is giving me the following errors:

```
error TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

3  return function<U extends {[key:T]:V},V>(record:U):V
                                ~~~
error TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'U'.

5   return record[prop];
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is this a limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you are looking for using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

```
function propertyMap<T extends string>(prop: T) {
  return function <U extends { [key in T]: V }, V>(record: U): V {
    return record[prop]
  }
}
```

Comment: This works; I also removed type `V` and replaced the nested function's return type with `U[T]`, because I was having trouble with return values being marked as `unknown`.